# Generic method that programatically returns a layout constraint based on Relative Layout c#

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, code-behind

I have a View, in this view I am adding components in code behind instead of using xaml, I have a relative layout and a class that creates a label `Lbl` and a button `MyButton` passing as parameters **width,height, img source, label text and color**.

```
var innerLayout = new RelativeLayout() { BackgroundColor = Color.Black };
var myCustomhBtn = new Custom(100, 120, "img.png", "the text of label", Color.White);
```

Now I want to add the `xConstraint` and `yConstraint` to each component.
All of them will be x and y constraints in the form:

```
            innerLayout.Children.Add(  
            myCustomhBtn.MyButton,
            xConstraint: Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) => {
                double x1 = parent.Width / 2 - myCustomhBtn.MyButton.Radius;
                double x2 = parent.Width - 2 * myCustomhBtn.MyButton.Radius;
                return (x1 + x2) / 2 + myCustomhBtn.MyButton.Radius/ 2;
            }),
            yConstraint: Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) => {
                double y1 = 0;
                double y2 = parent.Height / 2 - 2 * myCustomhBtn.MyButton.Radius;
                return (y1 + y2) / 2 - myCustomhBtn.MyButton.Radius;
            }));
        innerLayout.Children.Add(
            myCustomhBtn.Lbl,
            Constraint.RelativeToView(myCustomhBtn.MyButton.Radius, (parent, sibling) => {
                return sibling.X + myCustomhBtn.MyButton.Radius- myCustomhBtn .Lbl.Width / 2;
            }), 
            Constraint.RelativeToView(myCustomhBtn.MyButton.Radius, (parent, sibling) => {
              return sibling.Y - 18;
             }));
```

For the label I just want it to be `-18` up button for `y` and centered `x`

So esentially I would like to do something like

```
var innerLayout = new RelativeLayout() { BackgroundColor = Color.Black };
    var myCustomhBtn = new Custom(100, 120, "img.png", "the text of label", Color.White);
AddComponent(innerlayout, x,y);
```

but as each constraint has the form of `Func`

```
xConstraint: Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) => {return xxxx; })
```

I do not know how to create a generic method

How to do it?, or what would be the best approach?

Comment: Actually it's hard for me to understand what your problem is. What keeps you from putting the code from the first listing in a method? You can create the constraints from that method, too. Or do you want to pass the `Func`? You can do that without problems, too.

Comment: Anyway, I think you should think about your design and how you are using layouts. I don't know exactly what you are trying to achieve, but it seems overly complicated to me.

Comment: I am adding some buttons, and I just want to create a function that recives x and y, and returns the respective x or y Constraint

Comment: @Paul Kertscher  could you and an example function so I can tell if that is what I would like to achieve?

Comment: I tried to give an answer, but I don't know, if I got your problem right. If I got it wrong, please comment on it and I will try to refine.

Comment: With "what you are trying to achieve", I meant on the layout-level, not on the code level. What do you want your layout to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and I just want to create a function that recives x and y, and returns the respective x or y Constraint

You could (while I would not recommend that) create a method that returns a `Tuple` of `Constraint`s.

```
private (Constraint xConstraint, Constraint yConstraint) BuildConstraints(x, y)
{
    var xConstraint = Constraint.RelativeToParent(parent => /* whatever ... */);
    var yConstraint = Constraint.RelativeToParent(parent => /* whatever ... */);
    return (xConstraint, yConstraint);
}
```

But I would rather create one method for each constraint

```
Constraint BuildXConstraint(x)
{
    return Constraint.RelativeToParent(parent => /* whatever ... */);
}
```